# Image of probability measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ be a probability space. What is known about $P(\Sigma)$, the set of probabilities of events in $\Sigma$ by $P$?

Clearly, $P(\Sigma)$ contains $0$ and $1$ since $0=P(\varnothing)$ and $1=P(\Omega)$, and $P(\Sigma)$ is symmetric in the sense that, if $x\in P(\Sigma)$ then $1-x\in P(\Sigma)$.

Thus, one is looking for some characterization of the property that a given subset $S\subseteq[0,1]$ is $S=P(\Sigma)$ for some probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$.

More generally, one can ask whether $S=P(\Sigma)$ for some $n\geqslant2$, some probability spaces $(\Omega_i,\Sigma_i,P_i)$, $P=P_1\otimes P_2\otimes\cdots\otimes P_n$ and $\Sigma=\Sigma_1\otimes\Sigma_2\otimes\cdots\otimes\Sigma_n$.

Comment: The problem is original. Is there a specific context?

Comment: The first part appeared during the discussion in class. I'm trying to generalize this and find some information/articles about this problem.

Comment: OK. Rereading this, I fail to understand the generalization you have in mind in the last paragraph of the question. Could you explain?

Comment: If $S\subset[0,1]$ is not such that $S=P(\Sigma)$ for some probability space, is it possible that $\prod_{i\in I} S=\left(\prod_{i\in I}P_i\right)\left(\prod_{i\in I}\Sigma_i\right)$  for some probability spaces  $(\Omega_i,\Sigma_i, P_i)$ ?